# partitioning problem non allocated partition unused

Tags: partitioning

I have a dual boot on my aspire 3 with ubuntu and windows 11. When installing ubuntu, I Allocated it a relatively small space compared to windows. Now I would like to allocate more space is it still possible?

Here is an idea of what my partitioning looks like:

[disk partitioning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWkLc.png)

Comment: Yes, you can move the start boundary of the `/` (p5)  partition to the left, enlarging it by the whole of the non allocated space. However, you need to do that from a Live USB system, as the `/` partition can not be mounted at that time. On the Live USB system, use `gparted`. There are several questions on this website on how exactly to do that.

Comment: Understand any move left requires a copy & replace of all data on that partition. Any interruption totally corrupts data as some is  in one place and some in another.  Just make sure there are no interruptions & you have battery fully charged & plugged into mains. Alternatives may be to make make larger space as /home, move swap to end of space where /home is now & make it smaller & expand / into existing swap. [Move Home](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving)  Good backups of all systems required with any major change.

Comment: You'll have to boot from a Live USB, or your Install medium in "`Try Ubuntu`" mode. You cannot adjust a disk's partitions while any of them is mounted.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot! According to you, to which part should I add memory? I do not get well how it will affect my later use of the PC.